# Can I use constants to avoid Class instance variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

To become thread-safe, I need to refactor the Class instance variables in my code.

#### original

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Score < ApplicationRecord

  def self.init_score
    return @init_score if @init_score.present?

    @init_score = new(multiplier: 4.0)

    @init_score.readonly!
    @init_score
  end
end
```

`Score.init_score`

#### refactored

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Score < ApplicationRecord

  INIT_SCORE = self.init_score.freeze

  def self.init_score
    init_score = new(multiplier: 4.0)
    init_score.readonly!
  end
end
```

`Score::INIT_SCORE`

So this approach makes sense, is this a good solution?

I want to know if a const can be used as a cache.

Comment: I would just use a method (your first approach). it's all around better: no meaningful performance penalty, is more convenient to work with, doesn't smell.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with @SergioTulentsev. What is you concern about thread safety here?

Comment: @engineersmnky I actually missed the thread safety angle at first. I can see a race when two threads try to lazy-initialize the variable at ~the same time. They might get different objects. But this doesn't matter here, I think, because the object is not supposed to be mutable.

Comment: whereas the constant is set at class load time, presumably before any additional threads spawn.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that was kind of my point. class instance variables certainly can be exposed to thread safety issues but in this context the immutability (or intended immutability) of this object seems to counteract the concern.

Comment: @engineersmnky "intended" is a good qualifier. `readonly!` does nothing to prevent in-memory updates to `Score#multiplier`. `freeze` seems to work better.

Comment: Thanks folks, @SergioTulentsev, and [@]engineersmnky
Using only freeze looks like a good improvement, maybe probably I'll implement a singleton to cache it right and safely, it looks an overengineering but solve my problem. 
ref: https://betterprogramming.pub/design-pattern-1-singleton-308c896801d7